# speed of individual function and entire program

Tags: performance, matlab

I have large loop that contains abs([imaginary]).
It took me a lot of time to complete the program.
I tried multiple other ways to compute abs() such as when C is imaginary, (real(C)^2+imag(C)^2).^.5.
This result same as abs(C).
When I used tic,toc, (real(C)^2+imag(C)^2).^.5 was slightly faster. So I substituted and ran it again.
However profile shows that when I had abs() was much faster.
How can this happen and how can I make abs(C) process faster?

Comment: Does `abs` really add any substantial runtime to your program? I just benchmarked it and it processes at a speed of roughly 1GB/s. I don't think there is anything to optimize.

Comment: i find that abs is more and more faster than (real(C)^2+imag(C)^2).^.5 the bigger is the size of C. i guess there is some optimization, but no idea of which kind

Comment: abs() is in loop size of 1396018 and abs as total it takes about 6 minutes which is half the time of entire function takes. I just need slight performance improvement. And I don't know whats happening. When I tried with C with 1000 random imaginary numbers,  (real(C)^2+imag(C)^2).^.5 was like 20% faster than abs().

Comment: @Kane the bigger issue is that you perform 1396018 iterations through a loop. At that number of iterations *anything* inside the loop is going to appear slow. Maybe consider vectorizing if possible.

Comment: @Suever What if I cannot change about number of iteration?

Comment: @Kane we would likely need to see the full code to provide any suggestions.

Comment: @Suever I see. This is not my code and I do not know if I can provide. I am assistant to the writer. I do appreciate comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i take it form your comment that you are using large loops, matlab is not that efficent with those, example:

```
test = randn(10000000,2);
testC = complex(test(:,1),test(:,2));

%%vector
tic
foo = abs(testC);
toc

%%loop
bar = zeros(size(foo));

tic
for i=1:10000000
    bar(i) = abs(testC(i));
end
toc
```

gives you something like

```
Elapsed time is 0.106635 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.928885 seconds.
```

Thats why i would recommend to calculate abs() outside the loop. If replacing the loop in total is no option you can do so only in Parts. For exsample you could use your loop until you got all your complex numbers, end the loop, calc abs() then start a new loop with those results. Also if each iteration of your loop is independat of other iteration results you might want to look in `parfor` as an replacement for `for`-loops

Comment: I see. I will try your suggestion. Don't know if I can do with my code but it seems reasonable to me in general coding. Thanks